# Using other log4net logging levels than the usual ones

Tags: .net, log4net, log4net-configuration

I've realised that there is more levels than all, debug, info, warn, error and fatal, they are listed in the `log4net.Core.Level` class.

But how can I use them? I mean, in the `ILog` interface you have methods to use the usual ones, but what if you want to use "Fine" or "Emergency", etc?

Cheers.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In the following example `Log` is of type `ILog`.

```
Log.Logger.Log(null, log4net.Core.Level.Emergency, "Help!", null);
```

For each level you check their `Value` in order to know when they are disabled.

For log4net version 1.2.10.0 you have the following levels and associated cut off values:

```
OFF: 2147483647
EMERGENCY: 120000
FATAL: 110000
ALERT: 100000
CRITICAL: 90000
SEVERE: 80000
ERROR: 70000
WARN: 60000
NOTICE: 50000
INFO: 40000
DEBUG: 30000
FINE: 30000
TRACE: 20000
FINER: 20000
VERBOSE: 10000
FINEST: 10000
ALL: -2147483648
```

Note that some levels share the same values so disabling one of them will also disable the other, like for example TRACE and FINER.

Comment: I must be blind or something, I didn't see that property haha.

And can I use those levels also in the configuration file writing them capitalized?

Cheers.

Comment: @vtortola, yes you can use those levels in the configuration.

Comment: @vtortola, you were not blind. All the nice amenities of the basic levels like IsXxxEnabled, Xxx, XxxFOrmat are not available for the other levels so when using the ILog interface it is easy to miss them. It also means that using the other levels in the code requires more work.

Answer (score 5):

To extend on the good answer already provided:

You can also add the following extension method:

```
 static public void Notice( this ILog log, object message )
 { 
     log.Logger.Log( null, log4net.Core.Level.Notice, message, null);
 }
```

Then use as:

```
Log.Notice("Take note!");
```

Where Log is of type ILog