# Usage of log4net to Always Log a Value

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

I have select few places in my application where I'd like to *always* log values. I could simply use Log.Info() and leave it at that, but I'd prefer a solution that can't be disabled by an accidental change to the level configuration. In this case, as long is log4net is not disabled, I want these log statements to fire.

What's the best approach?

Just looking at [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675710/using-other-log4net-logging-levels-than-the-usual-ones) [information](http://www.l4ndash.com/Log4NetMailArchive%2Ftabid%2F70%2Fforumid%2F1%2Fpostid%2F14714%2Fview%2Ftopic%2FDefault.aspx) it looks like one option is to create a custom level with a value set above Emergency, but I don't know if that's a brutally awful hack with side effects I'm not realizing or a legitimate option. I couldn't find any clear guidance in the documentation.

Comment: Did you try my answer?  Did it help?

Answer (score 1):

I am not a log4net expert, but something like this might do what you want:

This code will get a named logger from the LogManager and will programmatically set its level to "ALL".  If you retrieve this logger later in your code, it will always log, even if the log level is set to OFF in the config file.

To test, set the root log level to "OFF" in the config file, then use the code below:

```
  log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("abc");
  log.Info("this won't log because root logger is OFF");

  //Reset the level
  log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger l = (log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger)log.Logger;

  l.Level = l.Hierarchy.LevelMap["ALL"];

  //Try to log again
  log.Info("this will log because we just reset abc's level to ALL");
```

I tested it and it does seem to work.

I found this information [here](http://rbovill.blogspot.com/2008/11/httpwwwmail-archivecomlog4net.html) and [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/log4net-user@logging.apache.org/msg02895.html).